# should I open the watch dog of redis distribution lock

Tags: redis, redisson

I am implementing the distribution lock by using redis `set if Not exists` command, now facing a issue that some distribution lock task spent more than expire time. This would cause some issue, and I read that redisson give a solution that called `watch dog`. the redisson may start a thread to renew the lock expire time if the task not finished in the expire time. My question is:

- is it a good practice to use the watch dog? because the watch dog thread will make the server pay resource, it will increase the resouce requrement by the number of distribution lock.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptors before using a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends. Normally we don't need a watch dog. Because in most cases, we can estimate the execution time of our code by some kink of metrics. And we can set the expire time a little larger than the task execution time. But if the execution time of the task is not stable, and we can not estimate it, then I think the watch dog is needed. Since lock-expire cases can occure more offenly.